# How to install missing locales for OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, locale

The es_AR locale is missing from /usr/share/locale, is it possible to generate it? How?

It should be the same as es_ES locale but using ARS instead of EUR for currency. Doing the es_AR.UTF-8 alone would be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just directories containing text files. Mix and match to your preferences.

You can create a copy of `en_ES` and edit `LC_CURRENCY` by either copying from another locale definition or editing all settings yourself. The settings are documented [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html), in section **7.3.3 LC_MONETARY**. One entry per line.

Using German (Euro currency) as example, `#` indicates start of my explanation which is not part of the file:

```
EUR  # International currency symbol and divider
Eu # Currency symbol (local) (I have honestly never seen this used in my life)
, # decimal point
. # digit group (e.g. thousands) separator
3;3 # grouping
 # positive sign (here: none)
- # negatice sign
2 # number of fractional digits (internationally)
2 # number of fractional digits (local)
1 # currency symbol before non-negative value
1 # currency symbol and sign string are separated by a space from the non-negative value
1 # currency symbol before negative value
1 # currency symbol and sign string are separated by a space from the negative value
1 # sign precedes both quantity and symbol for non-negative numbers
1 # sign precedes both quantity and symbol for negative numbers
```

The file does not contain the digit configuration twice as indicated on that web page.